# Show Div based on multiple drop down selections

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

```
<select name="main">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="1">2</option>
  <option value="1">3</option>
  <option value="1">4</option>
  <option value="1">5</option>
</select>
<select name="sub">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="1">2</option>
  <option value="1">3</option>
</select>
```

I have 2 seperate drop downs as seen here. I want to make it so that if they select main it will show a div for main with a text box equal to they number they select(ie. 4 will show 4 main textboxes for them to fill out) which I know how to do. The problem comes with sub I want them to show  a text box equal to the sub for each main select(ie if main is 3 and sub is 3 then each of the 3 main text box will be followed by 3 sub text boxes) I can make it show 3 or all but I can not figure out how to make it go based of the selection of both main and sub to ive me the exact fields I am looking for.   Do I just need to set in the function for the java script that if main == x then show xyz on the function for sub?

Comment: Can you show the html?

Comment: I misunderstood your question at first.. please check out my updated answer...

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this you'll have to:

- Use the `change` event on each select
- Take advantage of the `value` attribute on each option

***Demo:***

```js
const mainSelect = document.querySelector('select[name="main"]');
const subSelect = document.querySelector('select[name="sub"]');
const resultsDiv = document.getElementById("results");

mainSelect.addEventListener("change", event => {
  handleChange(event);
});

subSelect.addEventListener("change", event => {
  handleChange(event);
});

function handleChange(event) {
  let textboxes = "";
  let mainCount = Number(mainSelect.value);
  let subCount = Number(subSelect.value);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < mainCount; i++) {
    let t = "<input type='text' placeholder='main' /><br/>";
    
    for (let s = 0; s < subCount; s++) {
      t += "<input placeholder='sub' style='margin-left: 10px;' /><br/>"
    }
    
    textboxes += t;
  }
  
  resultsDiv.innerHTML = `<h4>Please fill these out</h4>${textboxes}`;
}
```

```html
<select name="main">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<br />
<select name="sub">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use onchange in the sub select:

```
<select name="sub" onchange="createSubInput(this)">

 function createSubInput (selected) {
      let mainSelectedValue = document.getElementById('main').value;

       for(let i=0; i< mainSelectedValue; i++) {
        for(let j=0; j< selected.value; j++) {
          // todo: create sub input by each main input
        }
      }
    }
```